# Fast to compile efficient sort algorithm (for JIT compilation)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, llvm, clang

I am building a compiler which produces c++ code into a character array which is translated by JIT-compiler Clang to LLVM-IR and then further JIT-translated to executable code (which is than executed).

I am processing large amounts of data and at one point, i need to sort an array of a *custom* data type. The data type is dynamically build by my compiler and different for every JIT compilation. Usually the elements are lexicographically compared by some numbers in it, however, the comparision might be more complex in rare cases (following some pointers and fancy string compares).

Now my question:
What is an efficient sort algorithm which can by JIT compiled by llvm *very fast* and on the same time is *very fast* at the execution?
Are there somewhere algorithms around which can be compiled fast and run fast at the same time?

My first idea was to just JIT-ing a comparision function and give it to qsort() as a pointer (i can link to external compiled functions in LLVM).
However, qsort is shockingly inefficient at execution time.
The alternative, using std::sort is shockingly inefficient during compile time due to its templates and stl-blubbla-sugar.

I did some performance test for execution for the following struct:

```
struct MyStruct {
int x;
long z;
bool operator<(const struct MyStruct& other) const { return (x < other.x) || (x==other.x&&z<other.z); }
}
```

1MB data runtimes:

- std::sort: 5 ms
- qsort: 14 ms
- self-written: 6 ms

1GB data runtimes:

- std::sort: 8.9 s
- qsort: 24 s
- self-written: 10.1 s

Unfortunately i do not have JIT compile times right now, but will post them in the future.

Currently it seems that my self written sort is better than qsort or std::sort, but i would rather like to use some library implementation.

Do you have any proposals on existing sort implementations which would be both fast in execution and for compilation?
Or are there maybe any other possibilities to speed up compiliation while having a fast sorting (only compile comparision function or something like that)?

By the way, here is my self-written (stolen from http://alienryderflex.com/quicksort/) sort routine (for JITing, i would not use a template Type but replacing it directly with the custom type, including "<="):

```
template< typename Type >
void self_written_sort(Type *arr, int elements) {
    #define  MAX_LEVELS  64
    Type piv;
    int beg[MAX_LEVELS], end[MAX_LEVELS], i=0, L, R, swap ;
  beg[0]=0; end[0]=elements;
  while (i>=0) {
    L=beg[i]; R=end[i]-1;
    if (L<R) {
      piv=arr[L];
      while (L<R) {
        while (arr[R]>=piv && L<R) R--; if (L<R) arr[L++]=arr[R];
        while (piv<=arr[L] && L<R) L++; if (L<R) arr[R--]=arr[L]; }
      arr[L]=piv; beg[i+1]=L+1; end[i+1]=end[i]; end[i++]=L;
      if (end[i]-beg[i]>end[i-1]-beg[i-1]) {
        swap=beg[i]; beg[i]=beg[i-1]; beg[i-1]=swap;
        swap=end[i]; end[i]=end[i-1]; end[i-1]=swap; }}
    else {
      i--;
}}}
```

Comment: "my self written sort is better than qsort or std::sort" - but according to the results you posted, std::sort won in both cases...

Comment: Also, whilst I can imagine that STL *source* code might be slow to compile (due to all the template/#include wizardry), I can't imagine that the corresponding IR is significantly different to anything else in terms of complexity (and therefore JIT speed).  Or are you saying that you're compiling the C++ *source* code itself at run-time?

Comment: Are you sure it is necessary to really compile the algorithm every time (I mean as opposed to only linking it every time)? If you only need to link it, then the algorithm itself could be as complicated (and runtime-optimized) as you want.

Comment: I think mergesort can be implemented in very little code size.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: The c++ source code is indeed compiled at runtime everytime (using Clang). to dialer: That is actually my question. If i do not compile the whole algorithm everytime, the compiler might not be able to inline accordingly the comparison/and or copy function. to nightcracker: mergesort might be an idea i will look at. Still, it uses extra memory (copies input) which is not good.

Comment: @dialer: to dialer: That is actually my question. If i do not compile the whole algorithm everytime, the compiler might not be able to inline accordingly the comparison/and or copy function.

Comment: @nightcracker: mergesort might be an idea i will look at. Still, it uses extra memory (copies input) which is not good.

Answer (score 2):

I would first try to pass a function pointer to `std::sort`, and thus use it in the `qsort` way:

- the algorithm itself is precompiled
- the comparison function is JITed and passed dynamically

I think it would still be superior to `qsort` because the algorithm would manipulate the memory meaningfully and only the comparison would be called (really).

Comment: Good idea, i will try this out. So this means i will also use an int(const void*,const void*) function ptr as qsort (actually bool(const void*,const void*) as std::sort uses only "less"), but pass it to std::sort. I will post performance numbers as soon as i tested it.

Comment: So far as I understand, the reason `std::sort` gets its advantage over `qsort` is because the comparison predicate can be inlined.

Comment: @eci: no, you would use a `bool(T const&, T const&)` function. C++ is typed. Also, you might want to "recognize" common comparators and switch to pre-optimized code (for example for `<`).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: it's one of the advantages, but some other advantages include the fact that all other operations (live moving memory around) are also typed. Inlining *is* a worthy optimization for small comparators, obviously.

Comment: @MatthieuM. When i would use bool(T const&, T const&) i would need to recompile (JIT) the sort algorithm for type T which would be very expensive especially for the templates and code sugar of std::sort. I thought your initial answer wanted to avoid that (and use some fixed compare function with a can handle-everything signature (void*,void*) such that we can precompile everything except the comparator).

Comment: @eci: then I misunderstood your question. I thought the type itself was stable (or at least, chosen among a small collection) and that only the function comparator varied. If the type also changes, then of course you will need to recompile `std::sort` specialization, so the scheme is not applicable.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes type T varies. Also, i do not see how i can use std::sort without templating. I guess i would need to write my own FakeType, which implements assignment (and swap) by memcpy, also an iterator which jumps address by size. The easier way for me was to rewrite the self-written sort from above, i.e.: `void my_fixed_sort(void *array, int element_count, int elem_size, cmp_func* f )` using `typedef int cmp_func ( const void*, const void* );` as compare function. Runtimes are faster than qsort (1MB: 9 ms, 1GB: 16 s), so qsort is out of the race (qsort also uses >log(n) extra-space).